# What is the purpose of the .mk file in android

Tags: android, makefile, android-make

I want to how a `.mk` file works and where I have to use it? I have some downloaded source code and it includes lots of `.mk` extension files and I am stuck not knowing how to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you came across a project using native code - [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html).
Check the samples provided on the link for more detailed information about building and running such a project.